# Simple Injector: How to register event handlers instances to the event dispatcher

Tags: asp.net-mvc, event-handling, domain-driven-design, publish-subscribe, simple-injector

I have an interface.

```
// Assembly: Common
public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    void HandleEvent(TEvent theEvent);
}

// Assembly: Common
public interface IDomainEvent
{
}

// Assembly: Common
public interface IEventDispatcher
{
    void Register(IEventHandler<IDomainEvent> handler);
    void Dispatch(IDomainEvent theEvent);
}

// Assembly: Membership
public sealed class MemberRegistered : IDomainEvent
{
    // event properties
}
```

Then on my ASP MVC 5 project I have event handler for the events.

```
public sealed class MemberRegisteredHandler : IEventHandler<MemberRegistered>
    {
        public MemberRegisteredHandler(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
        }

        private ApplicationUserManager userManager;

        public void HandleEvent(MemberRegistered theEvent)
        {
            User user = new User(
                theEvent.MemberId.ToString(),
                theEvent.Username,
                theEvent.PersonalInformation.Email);

            this.userManager.CreateUserWithRandomPassword(user);
        }
    }
```

On my Startup class

```
var container = new Container();

// TIP: For Simple Injector >= v4.3, instead use container.Collection.Register. 
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
               typeof(IEventHandler<>),
               container.RegisterAll,
               Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

container.Register<IEventDispatcher, SimpleEventDispatcher>();
```

With that, how can I get the `event dispatcher` and register all the event handlers into it?

I've tried

```
var eventDispatcher = container.GetInstance<IEventDispatcher>();

foreach (var handler in container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>>())
{
    eventDispatcher.Register(handler);
}
```

But its not working. the GetAllInstances method is not returning anything.

`Things to note:`
The `IEventDispatcher` is a dependency on my EF DbContext constructor and I have(right now) two contexts. `MembershipContext` and `IdentityAccessContext` which both derived from `EventDipatchingContext` that derives from `DbContext`.
Basically its `EventDispatchingContext : DbContext` then `MembershipContext : EventDispatchingContext`

The `EventDispatchingContext` is responsible for delegating the events to the event dispatcher `after its Commit() method is invoked`. They are not get fired instantly on my Domain Entites. I got this architecture from Jimmy Bogard's blog

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/

Do I need to make IEventDispatcher a singleton in this case? Why?

How to properly regsiter the handlers to the event dispatcher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prevent 'registering' the event handlers in your event dispatcher. Instead you should make the event dispatcher implementation part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). This way you can safely take a dependency upon the container from within the dispatcher as follows:

```
public class SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;
    
    public SimpleInjectorEventDispatcher(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Dispatch(IDomainEvent theEvent)
    {
        var handlerType =
            typeof(IEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(theEvent.GetType());
        
        var handlers = this.container.GetAllInstances(handlerType);
        
        foreach (dynamic handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.HandleEvent((dynamic)theEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that the `IEventDispatcher` interface now only contains a `Dispatch` method.

> Do I need to make IEventDispatcher a singleton in this case? Why?

You don't have to make the event dispatcher implementation a singleton, but since it has no dependencies and no state, it's wise to make it a singleton. This way its consumers can become singletons as well. The [more singletons the merrier](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/in-praise-of-the-singleton-object-graph/).

Comment: Thats much simpler! Is there a way to abstract the Container?

Comment: Of course, but that is usually useless for this type of infrastructural component that is part of your composition root. But either way, you can inject an `Func<Type, IEnumerable>` into the constructor instead `Container` and register the type as follows: `container.RegisterSingle<IEventDispatcher>(new SimpleEventDispatcher(container.GetAllInstances))`.

Comment: are there any drawback when all classes depending on IEventDispatcher will also become singleton? Actually I dont know the advantages and disadvantages of using singletons even outside the context of dependency injection.

Comment: @Daskul: You should strive to make your object graphs stateless and pass the state through the graph using method calls. In that case all your components will be stateless and depend solely on singletons. In that case there are only advantages. But if you have components with state on the other hand, making them singleton can cause race conditions and other multi-threading related bugs.

Comment: thank you for the information. It helps me a lot. still have plenty to chew :)